# How can I enable Mountain Lion Spellcheck in Google Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, spellcheck

Chrome's spellcheck has become cumbersome as of the new auto-correct spell check in Mountain Lion. I love that I don't have to go to the mouse and use a context menu for spell-checking---EXCEPT IN CHROME.

Is there any way to replace Chrome's spellcheck with Mountain Lion's?

Answer (score 2):

Spell check is a system service so by using the standard Mac control for a text box, chrome would magically get to use the service.

Since chrome isn't programmed to use the standard control (they wrote their own implementation) - you would need to either get the chrome devs to change the code or you would need to change it yourself and re-compile your version of Chrome. Both are likely to involve a serious amount of engineering since the code base is quite complex.

Comment: Yes, and I am not that advanced. Honestly, I don't understand why the Chrome devs haven't done this. Looks like I may be out of luck. But thanks anyhow!

Comment: The developers may have more details on the [why and how here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?can=2&q=spellcheck&cells=tiles). I can see why they want to code this so that it works everywhere (Mac / Windows / other) rather than change things _just for the Mac_. There are probably dozens of reasons for and against the change you seek. For most, it's just a ***no, it won't work.***

Comment: [Bug 90278](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=90278)  is "Support Lion spellcheck/autocorrect" -- filed July 2011, and not touched in over a year.  It seems like a rather low priority for them, unfortunately.